# Static methods called with base class property in specflow step from definition file refer to property as null

Tags: inheritance, selenium, tdd, specflow

I have a global base class in my solution that all of my tests inherit from, this class contain public IWebDriver property.
My project base class inherit from the solution base class and initialize the IWebDriver property.
My stepDeffinition class inherit from project base class and the beforeScenario property call the project base class TestInitialize that initialize the IWebDriver.

The global base class have TestCleanup tag to close the IWebDriver session but it uses static method that one of the properties of the method it the IWebDriver, when the static method is called the IWebDriver value is null (inside the method), although that when we passed it it wasn't.

Why my static method sees it as null??

```
[TestClass]
public class SolutionTestBase
{
    public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; protected set; }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void SubBaseTestCleanup()
    {
        if (WebDriver != null)
        {
            WebDriverFactory.QuitFromWebDriver(WebDriver, TestSettings);
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ProjectBaseTest : SolutionTestBase
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        WebDriver = WebDriverFactory.GetDriverFromConfig(currBrowser.Name, TestContext);
    }
}

[Binding]
public class StepDefinitions : ProjectBaseTest
{
    [BeforeScenario("ConsoleAnalytics"), DataSource(BrowsersRef)]
    public void BeforeAnalyticsScenario()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
}

public class WebDriverFactory
{
    public static void QuitFromWebDriver(IWebDriver webDrivers, TestSettings testSettings, int milliSeconds = 200)
    {

        if (/*Some Code*/)
        {
            /*
             * 
             * Some Code
             * */
        }

        else if (testSettings == TestSettings.Local)
        {
            webDrivers.Quit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mix your test setup/cleanup infrastructure between specflow and mstest. SpecFlow is a test generation tool. It will generate the `[Test]` and `[TestCleanup]` methods for you and so your classes should not use them.

If you want things to happen after your tests then you should use the SpecFlow infrastructure to do this ie use the `[AfterScenario]` tag in specflow

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the VS is calling the [TestCleanup] and the [AfterScenario]. if I want to inherit from this base class is there a way that the VS will not call the [TestCleanup]?

Comment: As I said you should not be using [TestCleanup] at all if you are using specflow, as this will just confuse things. You **MUST** remove all unit testing attributes from you classes and just use specflow. Move the code in you test clean up method into a method marked with [AfterScenario] and let specflow handle it for you.